# Numerical Inversion of an incomplete beta function expressed as gauss hypergeometric function using Mathematica

Tags: numerical-methods, inverse-function, hypergeometric-function, mathematica

I am currently working with this hypergeometric function ${_2}F_1$,

$\rho(r)=\frac{2b}{1-q}(1-(\frac{b}{r})^{1-q})^{\frac{1}{2}}{_2}F_1(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{q-1},\frac{3}{2},1-(\frac{b}{r})^{1-q})$

I have just started learning and using Mathematica and I just want to ask if  I can use Mathematica to construct and implement a simple routine to numerically invert the function $\rho(r)$ into $r(\rho)$? Note that $-\infty<q<1$, and $r,b>0$. Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be better suited for the [*Mathematica Stack Exchange*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). Please note that they generally require that you make an attempt and add whatever code you have tried.

Comment: Yes, ask at [Mathematica.Stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com). A start could be http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306450/how-do-i-get-the-inverse-of-a-function#5306512

Comment: A good start would be to show some effort and give the expression right away in Mathematica syntax. Moreover, there are several constants `b` and `q` in your formular. Without specifying them, a numerical solutions might not possible. The actual inversion, look up `InverseFunction` or `FindRoot` in the documentation. There are also already plenty of good answer to similar questions in [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com), some of them can also deal with parameters.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=b+InverseBetaRegularized%281+%2B+%28%28-1+%2B+q%29+x%29%2F%28b+beta%281%2F2%2C+1%2F%28-1+%2B+q%29%29%29%2C+1%2F%28-1+%2B+q%29%2C+1%2F2%29%5E%281%2F%28-1+%2B+q%29%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D) is the $q>1$ inverse, but you can extend it using the [series with recurrence coefficients](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahwts/lgsnotes/EJAM_Quantiles.pdf) and [this transformation](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/17/02/03/0002/). However, you may not get a closed form due to $I^{-1}_x(a,b)$’s domain if extending it.